# Rename SQL log and master database file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am working on SQL Server 2014. I want to know how can I rename the .ldf and .mdf files of my database after creating it? If it is possible what are the steps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't rename the files while they are in use, and don't make them "not in use" by stopping the SQL Server, it won't pick up on the change automatically.

The quickest way is as follows:

1. Detach the database with `EXEC sp_detach_db 'database_name'` or the appropriate dialogue in SQL Server Management Studio.
   The database must have no current connections otherwise SQL Server won't allow you to detach it - if you have trouble with this force that database into single user mode.
2. Rename the files as needed
3. Reattach the database which assuming you ave only a single data file and a single log files is done with `EXEC sp_attach_db 'database_name', 'full_path_to_mdf', 'full_path_to_ldf'`, for example: `EXEC sp_attach_db 'my_renamed_db', 'd:\dbs\data\my_renamed_db.mdf', 'd:\dbs\logs\my_renamed_db.ldf'`
   Again, the appropriate dialogue in SQL Server Management Studio can be used instead.

As you are specifying the database name in the call to `sp_attach_db`, this does the rename step also.

*Update:*

As Travis reminds me in the comments, `sp_attach_db` has been officially deprecated for a while and you should use the newer DDL method instead. The above example becomes:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_renamed_db
    ON (FILENAME = 'd:\dbs\data\my_renamed_db.mdf')
     , (FILENAME = 'd:\dbs\data\my_renamed_db.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

Slightly safer even, you can avoid completely detaching the database at all by setting it offline and modifying the file locations instead (you still have to manually move or rename the files though):

```
ALTER DATABASE my_renamed_db SET OFFLINE;
ALTER DATABASE my_renamed_db MODIFY FILE (NAME='data_file_name', FILENAME='d:\dbs\data\my_renamed_db.mdf');
ALTER DATABASE my_renamed_db MODIFY FILE (NAME='log_file_name', FILENAME='d:\dbs\data\my_renamed_db.ldf');
ALTER DATABASE my_renamed_db SET ONLINE;
```

You can move/rename the files any time after the `SET OFFLINE` but before `SET ONLINE`.

If you don't know the logical filenames you can look them up in SSMS or via

```
SELECT f.name, f.physical_name 
FROM   master.sys.databases d 
JOIN   master.sys.master_files f 
       ON d.database_id = f.database_id 
WHERE  d.name = 'my_renamed_db'
```

If moving `tempdb` things are different: you can't offline it and it is recreated every time the server starts. Instead make the `ALTER DATABASE MODIFY FILE` calls and restart the SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure for moving system databases is documented in the SQL Server Books Online under the [Move System Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx) topic.

In summary:

1.Run SQL Server Configuration Manager, located in the Configuration Tools program group.

2.Right-click the instance of SQL Server (for example, SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)) and choose Properties under the SQL Server Services node.

3.In the SQL Server Properties dialog box, click the Startup Parameters tab.

4.In the Existing parameters box, select the –d parameter to move the master data file. Click Update to save the change.

In the Specify a startup parameter box, change the parameter to the new path of the master database.

5.In the Existing parameters box, select the –l parameter to move the master log file. Click Update to save the change.

In the Specify a startup parameter box, change the parameter to the new path of the master database.

The parameter value for the data file must follow the -d parameter and the value for the log file must follow the -l parameter. The following example shows the parameter values for the default location of the master data file.

-dC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf

-lC:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf

If the planned relocation for the master data file is E:\SQLData, the parameter values would be changed as follows:

-dE:\SQLData\master_newname.mdf

-lE:\SQLData\mastlog_newname.ldf

6.Stop the instance of SQL Server by right-clicking the instance name and choosing Stop.

7.Move the master.mdf and mastlog.ldf files to the new location and rename as desired.

8.Restart the instance of SQL Server.

9.Verify the file change for the master database by running the following query.

```
SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('master');
```

Comment: I doubt very much the question is about the `master` database. From the title alone it might indeed seem so. However, in the post itself the OP is unambiguously asking, *"how can I rename the .ldf and .mdf files of **my database**"*

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is simple and well documented for both user and system databases, please see here:

[Moving User Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms345483.aspx)

[Moving System Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

It's possible. But mostly avoid to rename of (.mdf) or (.ldf) live accessing database file.

There are some couple of steps through which you can do that through T-SQL as below mention steps:-

```
1) Set Database in single user mode
2)Rename the Database
3)Set Database to Multi-User Mode
4)Rename Logical File Name
5)Checking Physical name
6)Detach Database
7)Attach New Database
```

For ref  http://blog.codespecies.com/2013/07/rename-a-database-and-its-mdf-and-ldf-files-in-sql-server/  and

http://mediumcube.com/mctalk/2013/07/05/how-to-rename-mssql-database-mdf-and-ldf-files/.

NB:- Always consult to Database Team before Executing T-SQL file in live database in production Server. Because it's directy affect in DB.