# Do database connections get automatically reconnected if a database is restored?

Tags: sql-server

I'm not a DBA/SQL expert, so please excuse me if this is the wrong forum to post in.

There's an issue with our production database where log files are not being stored in LDF format. DBA wants to delete our production database and restore a full backup to fix the issue, is this best practice? There's multiple active connections to this database from applications, do these connections automatically get reconnected when the database is restored?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of misunderstanding in the wording of your questions, but I'll give you a quick explanation to each of them.

> **Do database connections get automatically reconnected if a database is restored?** (Title of Question)

It depends on how the applications were built/programmed. If an existing connection gets killed on the server side and if an error handling has been implemented in the application that looks for dropped connections, then your application might successfully reconnect to your database (server).

> **There's an issue with our production database where log files are not being stored in LDF format.** (Not a question, but a wrong observation)

The Transaction Log of the database will always be stored using the "LDF" format. The file itself might not have an extension denoting it as an `*.ldf` file. Or put differently: The SQL Server Database Engine will always write the information pertaining to transactions to the Transaction Log file, regardless of the name of the file.

> **DBA wants to delete our production database and restore a full backup to fix the issue, is this best practice?**

Best practice would have been having created with the database with the desired file names in the first place.

Backing up a the database and restoring it while changing the file names is possibly the easiest way to "rename" the relevant files.

The second best option would be to detach the database and then rename the files and bring the database back using the `CREATE DATABASE .... FOR ATTACH` syntax as mentioned in this answer [Rename SQL log and master database file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117717)

Another method to rename or move user database files is detailed in the [Planned Relocation Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-user-databases?view=sql-server-ver16#planned-relocation-procedure) in the SQL Server documentation. In summary, ...

1. ...rename database file(s) with`ALTER DATABASE`,
2. ...take database offline using `ALTER DATABASE...SET OFFLINE`,
3. ...rename files on file system, and finally
4. ...`ALTER DATABASE...SET ONLINE`.

**However, it doesn't matter which solution you use as the database will be unavailable in any case.**

> **There's multiple active connections to this database from applications, do these connections automatically get reconnected when the database is restored?**

See my first answer to your initial question.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your valuable addition to my answer. I appreciate it. You could have added it as additional answer and garnered some unicorn points yourself. However, I have absolutely no objections having your knowledge in my answer. I had that info in mind, but couldn't recall the actual location.

Comment: No problem. My thought was a single answer with all the info consolidated would better benefit the community.

Comment: "if an error handling has been implemented in the application that looks for dropped connections" -- if the application has to take special action, it doesn't count as "automatic" in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> do these connections automatically get reconnected when the database is restored?

Hell, no!

Restoring a database is, perhaps surprisingly, a *destructive* process.
Whilst it's happening, your tables may or may not exist and may or may not have [complete] data in them.
For this reason, all [Application] connections must be cut at the start of the process and no new connections allowed until the restoration process is complete and checks have been carried out on the restored Data.
This is *not* an activity to be taken *lightly* (and your DBA should *know* this).

> There's an issue with our production database where log files are *not being stored in LDF format ...*

They might not be stored in files *named* with **.LDF** extensions, but that absolutely *will* be stored in the correct, internal, format.  Your database simply wouldn't work if this were not the case (unless it's running without *any* logging which, for a *Production* system, is a "Hanging Offence", in my book).

> ... DBA wants to delete our production database and restore a full backup to fix the issue ...

I'm pretty certain that SqlServer log files *cannot* be renamed whilst the database is running, so restoring the backup *will not* correct the "file naming issue" which, as I said before, isn't really an issue at all.

If there really *is* a problem with the logging sub-system, then that's a much bigger problem that needs to be addressed urgently but, again, *destroying* all the transactional data stored since the last backup was taken is *not* the answer.
Indeed, if the transaction logs really *aren't* being recorded correctly, then the only backup they might be *able* to restore to will be that last "full" backup, however long ago *that* was taken!

Stopping the database, immediately backing it up, changing the logging mode and restarting the database is about as far as you should need to go.